# MKMapView Weirdness With MKMapCamera

Tags: mkmapview, ios7

I need to figure out how to not let MKMapView in ios7 reset the heading of it's internal MKMapCamera's heading when at high altitudes.

Here's the issue:

When at low altitudes, the user can easily rotate the map 360 degrees.
At high altitudes, the user can begin to rotate the map, but the mapview quickly "rubber bands" the heading back to 0.

Changing the heading of the internal MKMapCamera programmatically works fine at high altitudes. Here's where my concern comes in:

I need to show north up at all times, but still allow the user to zoom in and out from the map. I can programmatically keep the heading given the course from CLLocation. If a user were to pinch(zoom out) of the map though, MKMapView would immediately tell it's internal camera "Oh no! you're too high, better go ahead and rotate you to 0 heading again."

Is there anyway to tell MKMapView to NOT EVER set it's internal MKMapCamera automatically?

Comment: This is a contradiction " I need to show north up at all times, but still allow the user to zoom in and out from the map. I can programmatically keep the heading given the course from CLLocation" Do you need north up (default when non rotatet map) or at CLLocation.heading value?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say I need to show course up at all times. Course is different from heading. Heading is gathered from the device's compass. Course is calculated over time and represents the direction you are moving in.

Comment: OK, Do you use 2D view (top down) or a camera with perspective view? What is hight altitude? (country visible, whole earth?)

Comment: This would be strictly top down. No perspective. Highest altitude would probably be fitting the entire US on the map.

Comment: Ah interesting, I tried it out with my app. Same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in follow vehicle mode, I would reduce/limt the zoom level such that the unwanted back rotation does not happen.

Caluclate the zoom level by calulating the number of meters of the map diagonal.
Manually find out which "zoom" value is safe.